# Display only the new books that user has taken. Ignore repeated ones

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with user id and book id.

data:

```
Userid bookid
    403   B053
    403   B103
    403   B053
    403   B053
    1711  B008
    1711  B171
    1711  B008
    1711  B008
    1200  B008
    1200  B171
```

How do i get the data where user id is same but book id is different?

I tried something like:

```
df[(df.userid == df.userid) & (df.bookid != df.bookid)]
```

It returns only empty result

expected opt:

```
Userid bookid
    403   B053
    403   B103
    1711  B008
    1711  B171
    1200  B008
    1200  B171
```

Multiple users might have taken the same book here. So dropping duplicates won't work here.

Comment: Check now. Added 2 more rows\

Comment: Changed the title. Makes the question more clear

Comment: Can you check `df = df.drop_duplicates(['Userid','bookid'])` ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong dupe, now it was changed.

Comment: Buddy, That does not solve my problem too

Comment: Show data where user id is same but book id is different. This is what i want

Comment: For me working very nice, I get expected output from your sample data.

Comment: On my machine, the code by @jezrael is giving the expected output you have put.

Comment: Yeah. Fine now even for me. I had some error

Comment: Please put this as the answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

This should work always. You drop duplicates using userid and bookid and later you find duplicates using userid only

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['userid','bookid'])

df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['userid'])]
```